# Amazon S3 does not seem to be triggering Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an email parser set up with Amazon SES, S3 and Lambda.

When an object is placed into an S3 bucket, it triggers the Lambda function and sends an email out with SES.

However, Lambda does not always seem to get triggered when an object is placed into S3.

When testing the Lambda functions with the S3 event, it works perfectly. Yet the same event does not trigger the lambda when placed in the bucket.

I'm not sure where to go about debugging this. Would appreciate if anyone has any insights on this.

Comment: Can you show your event notification trigger setup on the S3 bucket?

Comment: What does CloudWatch Logs for the Lambda function show in the 'failing' cases? Is the Lambda triggered by S3 upload sometimes, or never?

Comment: Please send more data. What does your lambda look like? Check CloudWatch for your Lambda. Are you sure your lambda is not running? Maybe SES is not sending the emails out? Check the SES console too for errors.